# How to speed up remote mysql connection

Tags: mysql

I have an apache webserver in one datacenter that connects to a mysql server in a remote datacenter. Other than optimizing queries and the db, is there something that I can do to speed things up with this connection?

I cannot put these in the same datacenter at the moment.

Comment: Put them both in the same data centre, or talk to the provides about a faster connection.

Comment: Without analyzing your particular case too much, latency is going to be the killer so as _few_ queries as possible is probably a good idea. If you can overlap queries using an async api that may help too. Besides that, not much to do except improving the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Apache web server running something like a PHP web application? If so, you could try relocating the web application--using PHP FPM or similar for your programming language--to the same data center where the database resides. Then reconfigure Apache to proxy the application requests to the remote application servers. This will reduce the number of remote hops between servers to one round trip per request as the application's (likely) multiple trips to the database will effectively be local.